# Trying to click on a button with multiple texts on it using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I am trying to locate a button according to one of the texts that are on it. The compiler gives me this message: )
...is not a valid XPath expression.

`vyber2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath( '//*[contains(text(), " komplexe Behandlung \"Classic\" ")]')`

On the photo is a picture of the dropdown. I need to locate the package name on one of the options and click it. (For example, I need to click on the "Komplexe Behandlung Classic" package [as shown on this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UpLpO.png).

My code to open the dropdown menu:

```
`#open the dropdown menu
vyber1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="packageSelectorContainer"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div')
    # Make click in that button
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(vyber1).click(vyber1).perform()

#wait again
timeout = 5
WebDriverWait(driver, timeout)
try:
    element_present = EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, '//*[@id="packageSelectorContainer"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[3]'))
    WebDriverWait(driver, timeout).until(element_present)
except TimeoutException:
    print("Timed out waiting for page to load")
#pick the desired package based on its name
vyber2 = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
    '//*[@id="packageSelectorContainer"]/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/ul/li[3]')
    # Make click in that button
ActionChains(driver).move_to(vyber2).click(vyber2).perform()`
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you post the link to the webpage that contains the button?

Comment: Sure! Here it is: https://www.sanatoriums.com/de/karlsbad/kurhotel-imperial-991/preise-zimmer?ar=2021-09-18&de=2021-10-02&ro=120&se=fbt

Comment: From that link, what is the process to access the panel on which the button resides?

Comment: I updated the question so you can see the code... thanks

Comment: When I load the page and click the dropdown, I am only presented with two dropdown options, and `komplexe Behandlung "Classic"` is auto selected each time. Is it possible that the number of dropdown options can vary, or is there another process by which the full set of dropdown options (as shown in your screenshot) can be toggled?

Comment: I believe that it can vary based on the location you are in. I need to handle the version shown to germans. But what I need to do is to select any other option that is not currently selected based on its name...

Comment: I added an answer below, let me know how it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

One way to grab button options with text `komplexe Behandlung "Classic"` that are not currently selected is to use Javascript via `driver.execute_script`:

```
from selenium import webdriver
d = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
d.get('https://www.sanatoriums.com/de/karlsbad/kurhotel-imperial-991/preise-zimmer?ar=2021-09-18&de=2021-10-02&ro=120&se=fbt')
elems = d.execute_script("""
  function* get_buttons(text){
     for (var i of document.querySelectorAll('div.flex-item.person-package.dropdown ul.dropdown-menu li.flex-grid')){
        if (!i.getAttribute('class').includes(' selected')){
           if (i.querySelector('div.package-title').textContent.includes(text)){
              yield i
           }
        }
     }
  }
  return [...get_buttons('komplexe Behandlung \"Classic\"')]
""")
```

Comment: I was not able to make it work :( but thank you so much!

Comment: Also sorry for a late response, I was super sick for couple of days and could not code